# How to design the database for a card game points counting app?

Tags: database

I would like to write an app for counting the points in a card game. Here's how the game works:

- the game uses poker cards to play
- There's no maximum number of players, but I will limit it to 8 so it's easier to design the database.
- I'm not gonna go into how to play the game, but after each game, the winner is the player who has no cards left in his hand, every other player will have a point (number of cards left * a factor)
- A match consists of a number of games. After a match, the player with the least points wins.

Here's my design of the app's database:

### MATCH table:

```
- MatchID: primary key, integer
- Date: 
- Player1: player name, varchar
- Player2: varchar
- Player3: varchar
- Player4: ..
- Player5: ..
- Player6: ..
- Player7: ..
- Player8: ..
```

### POINTS table:

```
- MID: foreign key reference to MATCH.MatchID
- GameID: the ID of each game in a match, integer
- PID: should reference to Player 1-8
- Points: integer
```

An Example of the POINTS table (4 players):

> | MID | GameID | PID | Points |
>
> | 1   | 1      | 1   | 5      |
>
> | 1   | 1      | 2   | 3      |
>
> | 1   | 1      | 3   |  0      |
>
> |  1   |  1      |  4   |  2      |
>
> | 1   |   2     |  1   |   0     |
>
> |  1   |    2    |   2  |    10    |
>
> |   1  |   2     |  3   |   20     |
>
> |   1  |   2     |  4   |   30     |
>
> ...

My questions are:

1. how can I reference the POINTS.PID to Player 1-8 in the MATCH table? I was thinking matching the number of PID with the column name Player#, but it doesn't sound like a proper solution.
2. is there a better way to design this database?
3. if there's no limit on the number of players, how should I design this database?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless the number of players is low (like 2) and you are certain that it is fixed for all time, you probably do not want to represent players as columns in your MATCH table.  Rather, you should have a separate MATCH_PLAYERS table to indicate the players in the match:

```
MATCH table:(MatchID,  MatchDate)

MATCH_PLAYERS table:(MatchID, PlayerID, PlayerName)
```

Where {MatchID, PlayerID} is the primary key of the MATCH_PLAYERS table.

This should answer most of your questions/problems.